# Oracle SQL store current sequence value

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I store the current sequence value into a variable so I can use it somewhere else after the sequence has been incremented.

I basically want to store the current sequence value and then use it to select row from my table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySequence
    INCREMENT BY 5
    START WITH 100;

DECLARE myVar NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
    myVar := mySequence.CURRVAL;
END;

INSERT INTO myTable (my_id, my_datetime)
SELECT  mySequence.NEXTVAL,
        my_datetime + 5,     
FROM myTable
WHERE my_id = myVar;
```

Comment: I suppose the `END;` belongs after the insert statement? So you are trying to find the row with the greatest ID, take its datetime and use it for the new row? Be aware that a value drawn from a sequence hasn't necessarily been used in the table. Another session might have drawn it and not yet committed. Or the value got drawn but then dismissed. So you might want to change your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to know what sequence value was generated by a sequence, you have two easy options:

1. Use the `RETURNING` clause:

   ```
   INSERT INTO myTable (my_id, my_datetime)
   VALUES(mySequence.NEXTVAL,SYSDATE)  
   RETURNING my_id INTO myVar;
   ```

   Now you may use it any way you like:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     INTO var_exists
     FROM myTable
    WHERE my_id = myVar;
   ```
2. Or, even more simply, assign the sequence to the variable directly, before the insert:

   ```
   myVar := mySequence.NEXTVAL;

   INSERT INTO myTable (my_id, my_datetime)
   VALUES(myVar,SYSDATE);
   ```

   Now you can do anything else you want with `myVar`.

If however your goal is to create a new row based on the previous row, then you need to use `MAX` to find the last row:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (my_id, my_datetime)
SELECT mySequence.NextVal,
       my_Datetime + 5
  FROM myTable
 WHERE my_id = (SELECT MAX(my_id)
                  FROM myTable);
```

But if you do this there's really no point in using a sequence at all, for then you can simply increment:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (my_id, my_datetime)
SELECT my_id + 1,
       my_Datetime + 5
  FROM myTable
 WHERE my_id = (SELECT MAX(my_id)
                  FROM myTable);
```

Sequences are used as surrogates for an otherwise undesirable (or unavailable) natural key, and make most sense when inserting new values without any dependency on existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

The `currval` doesn't make sense in general before you've called `nextval`.  You could have one session at time t1 that got a value of 1, another session at time t2 got a value of 21, then at time t3 the first session got a value of 2.  So 21 is the largest value that has been retrieved from the sequence but 2 is the most recent value any session has retrieved.   And some of those might be visible to you because the transaction has committed and others might not yet be visible.

Depending on the problem you are really trying to solve, you could select the `max(my_id)` value or the `my_id` value with the largest `create_date`.